# Put two figures side by side

Tags: floats, minipage, subcaption

There are already several threads that deal with this: they suggest having one figure and putting putting minipages inside, or using the `subcaption` package and having `subfigure` environments. However, I've tried both of these approaches and I'm still going wrong:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=0pt]
\Tree [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {a 'we'} ]
        [.T$'$
            [.T \node(li){li 'eat$_i$'}; ]
            [.VP
                [.Spec t ]
                [.V$'$ 
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {saka 'rice'} ]
                    [.V \node(t){t$_i$}; ] ] ] ] ]
\draw [->] (t) .. controls +(south:3) and +(south:3) .. (li);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}\hfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=0pt]
\Tree [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {a 'we'} ]
        [.T$'$
            [.T \node(li){la 'have'}; ]
            [.VP
                [.Spec t ]
                [.V$'$ 
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {saka 'rice'} ]
                    [.V \node(t){li 'eaten'}; ] ] ] ] ]
\draw [red,->] (t) .. controls +(south:3) and +(south:3) .. (li);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Get rid of the blank lines between the `minipage`s.

Comment: A blank line indicates a paragraph break, even if it is within a `figure`. As such, the second tree is in a new paragraph, which starts on a new line.

Comment: I've been bitten by this few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not leave blank lines between the two objects; a blank line is just `\par`, so the second object starts a new paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.85,sibling distance=0pt]
\Tree [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {a 'we'} ]
        [.T$'$
            [.T \node(li){li 'eat$_i$'}; ]
            [.VP
                [.Spec t ]
                [.V$'$ 
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {saka 'rice'} ]
                    [.V \node(t){t$_i$}; ] ] ] ] ]
\draw [->] (t) .. controls +(south:3) and +(south:3) .. (li);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}% <- this is important here
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.85,sibling distance=0pt]
\Tree [.TP
        [.DP \edge[roof]; {a 'we'} ]
        [.T$'$
            [.T \node(li){la 'have'}; ]
            [.VP
                [.Spec t ]
                [.V$'$ 
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {saka 'rice'} ]
                    [.V \node(t){li 'eaten'}; ] ] ] ] ]
\draw [red,->] (t) .. controls +(south:3) and +(south:3) .. (li);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I increased the width for the `minipage`s and scaled down the trees so they fit side by side without producing overfull `\hbox`es.

The powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package could be of interest for you; it's very versatile for building trees.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple! Thank you, and I'm looking into `forest` as we speak.