# Displaying two plots side by side not displaying titles correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, minipage

I’m writing a report and using the following code to display a bode-diagram. To save some space (I have several of these figures), I’ve displayed them side by side, but the title of the right plots’s in the left plot and it doesn’t improve by changing 0.5\linewidth to 0.45\linewidth...

Anyone can help?

A code sample:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
%data
f,Df,VP,DVP,VS,DVS,phi,Dphi,T
0.05,0.0004,9.61,0.01,197.6,0.1,178,1,0.020562
0.1,0.0001,9.65,0.01,199.4,0.1,178,1,0.020663
0.2,0.0004,9.7,0.03,200.7,0.2,178.6,0.2,0.020691
0.5,0.0002,9.75,0.01,201.7,0.2,179.5,0.5,0.020687
1,0.0003,9.77,0.01,201.3,0.2,180,0.3,0.020604
2,0.001,9.76,0.01,205,0.3,180.5,0.4,0.021004
5,0.002,9.85,0.01,199.5,0.2,180.5,0.1,0.020254
10,0.01,9.85,0.01,198.3,0.3,180.5,0.5,0.020132
20,0.006,9.85,0.01,197.5,0.7,180.5,0.2,0.020051
50,0.002,9.85,0.01,195.5,0.3,180,1,0.019848
60,0.02,9.86,0.01,193.5,0.7,179.5,4,0.019625
70,0.02,9.81,0.01,190,0.7,177.5,0.5,0.019368
79.99,0.04,9.86,0.01,188.9,0.6,172,0.6,0.019158
90.01,0.02,9.87,0.01,223.5,0.1,167,0.5,0.022644
94.99,0.03,9.73,0.01,240.8,0.8,170.9,0.3,0.024748
100,0.04,9.87,0.01,294.7,0.5,173.5,0.8,0.029858
150,0.1,9.85,0.04,296.9,0.5,183.5,0.6,0.030142
200.1,0.1,9.8,0.05,313.8,0.6,207,1,0.03202
299.9,0.2,9.77,0.02,256.9,0.4,215,1,0.026295
400,0.6,9.6,0.06,167.9,0.9,140,1,0.01749
450,1,9.72,0.01,385.2,0.4,158,1,0.03963
500,1,9.63,0.07,529.7,0.7,177,1,0.055005
600,1,9.6,0.03,861,2,207,1,0.089688
700,0.2,9.75,0.02,1206,1,248,0.4,0.12369
800,0.6,9.41,0.01,1168,1,70.8,0.5,0.12412
900,1,9.4,0.02,1011,6,318,1,0.10755
1000,1,9.32,0.01,905,3,340,1,0.097103
1500,2,9,0.01,757,1,111,1,0.084111
2000,2,8.7,0.01,375,1,180,1,0.043103
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
%Bode-diagram (met fase) opdracht 1.2
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel=frequentie $f (\kilo\hertz)$,
    ylabel=transferfunctie $T\ (\frac{\volt}{\volt})$,
    grid=both, 
    ymin = 0.01,
    ymax = 0.4,
    ytick={0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4},
    yticklabels={,0.02,0.03,,0.05,,0.07,,,0.1,0.2,0.3,},
    minor grid style={gray!25}, 
    major grid style={gray!25}]
\addplot table[x=f,y=T,col sep=comma]{data.dat};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Amplitude Bode-diagram $\dfrac{V_S}{V_P}$.\label{bodeAO12}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    ymode=normal,
    ytick={0,45,-45,90,-90,135,180,225,270,315,360},
    ymin=-10,
    xlabel=frequentie $f (\kilo\hertz)$,
    ylabel=fase $\phi (\degree)$,
    grid=both, 
    minor grid style={gray!25}, 
    major grid style={gray!25}]
    \addplot table[y=phi,x=f,col sep=comma]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{Frequentie Bode-diagram $\dfrac{V_S}{V_P}$.\label{bodeFO12}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Bode-diagram $\dfrac{V_S}{V_P}$.\label{BO12}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the blank line between `minipage`s?

Comment: As @cmhughes says, remove the blank line. Basically same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171275/put-two-figures-side-by-side/171277#171277

Comment: @cmhughes and Torbjørn: Thanks! It helped indeed! But now I’ve another problem: my right axes does’t display correctly, it is embedded inside the left graph...

Comment: That is because the graphs are too wide, not fitting into the `minipage`. If you look at the log you will probably find two warnings about `overfull hbox`es. Add `width=\linewidth` to the `axis` options.